# How do I contact Facebook about a false report when I'm blocked?

Tags: facebook

So, apparently I posted a digitally created picture as a cover photo for humorous purposes, and somebody reported it and Facebook took it down for nudity and suspended my account for several days. (Since I kept re-uploading it.) The thing is that the picture is only being used for humorous purposes despite some of my friends saying it implies something sexual (which it does not seem like that to me), and according to Facebook's policy on nudity (as of this question being posted) it states the following:

> We remove photographs of people displaying genitals or focusing in on fully exposed buttocks. We also restrict some images of female breasts if they include the nipple, but we always allow photos of women actively engaged in breastfeeding or showing breasts with post-mastectomy scarring. We also allow photographs of paintings, sculptures, and other art that depicts nude figures. Restrictions on the display of both nudity and sexual activity also apply to digitally created content unless the content is posted for educational, humorous, or satirical purposes. Explicit images of sexual intercourse are prohibited. Descriptions of sexual acts that go into vivid detail may also be removed.

The picture basically does not show any sexual intercourse or nudity at all. It consists of two animals (both are Pokemon Eeveelutions) and one of the animals barely has his rear-end showing while the other one seems to be doing something involving popsicles in a humorous way. How do I contact Facebook about this so I could use it as a cover photo again and not worry about getting my account suspended?

Answer (score 5):

It is not necessary that what is humorous for you, would be humorous for others also. To know about what's allowed on Facebook, please review the [Facebook Community Standards](https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards).

[Facebook Says](https://www.facebook.com/help/103873106370583):

> We disable Facebook accounts that don't follow the Facebook Terms. Some violations include:
>
> - Continued prohibited behavior after receiving a warning or multiple warnings from Facebook.
> - Unsolicited contact with others for the purpose of harassment, advertising, promoting, dating or other inappropriate conduct.
> - Use of a fake name.
> - Impersonation of a person or entity, or other misrepresentation of identity.
> - Posting content that doesn't follow the Facebook Terms
>
> Please review the Facebook [Statement of Rights and Responsibilities](https://www.facebook.com/policies) to learn more about our policies. If you think your account was disabled by mistake you can [**submit an appeal**](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/260749603972907).

In your case use the above link and submit an appeal.